# Mobiliy gem: Adding translations to an existing model (that already has a lot of records)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mobility

What's the easiest way to add translation capabilities to an existing model and automatically migrate the existing records?

The globalize gem provides a method `create_translation_table` with an option `migrate_data: true`, is there an equivalent for mobility?

Comment: There is unfortunately no such equivalent for Mobility currently.

Comment: As I have decided to use column storage option, it's not needed anymore in my case, as I can simply rename the existing columns (e.g. `title` to `title_en`).

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround I found when working with the gem using the **:key_value** Strategy
is to create a migration for each table and re-saving the value of the column using `[:column_name]`

Example:
If we Have a **Post** Table and I want to add it's **name** attribute to translations:
The Mobility migration(s) must be executed and `post.rb` must include:

```
 # post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    extend Mobility
    translates :name, type: :string
end
```

Then update the records to reflect the value of the default language (assuming `application.rb` has `config.i18n.default_locale = :de` and `initializers/mobility.rb` defines `locale_accessors [:de, :en, :sl]`

```
Post.all.each do |post|
  post.update(name_de: post[:name])
end
```

Then verify:

```
> Post.last.name_de
> Post.last.name_en
> Post.last.name_sl
```